# jQuery - selecting every .class member except the parent of $(this)

Tags: jquery

how do I select every class member except the one that is the parent of $(this)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
$(".your-class").not($(this).parent())
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.myClass').not(this.parentNode);
```

This will have significantly better performance than using `$(this).parent()`, because it doesn't involve creating a new jQuery object.

Comment: thanks, but I actually had to do things to other children of said parent (yikes, this would be a scary quote)... and I don't know how to get to them from this parentNode whatever that is

Comment: @A-OK By building a jQuery object -- Steve's solution is definitely better for what you want. Mine has [better performance](http://jsperf.com/parent-vs-parentnode) taken by itself, however.